# Add new function signature for python and js in OpenCV

Tags: javascript, python, opencv

I've updated the grabCut function (`opencv-master/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp`) and also added some new functions in the `imageproc` module. For that I've updated the `opencv-master/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp` file as:

```
CV_EXPORTS_W std::vector<std::vector<Point>> grabCut( InputArray img, InputOutputArray mask, Rect rect,
                           InputOutputArray bgdModel, InputOutputArray fgdModel,
                           int iterCount, int mode = GC_EVAL );

CV_EXPORTS_W std::vector<std::vector<Point>> grabCut_slim( InputArray img, InputOutputArray mask, Rect rect,
                               InputOutputArray bgdModel, InputOutputArray fgdModel,
                               int iterCount, int mode = GC_EVAL );

CV_EXPORTS_W std::vector<std::vector<Point>> paintselection( InputArray img, InputOutputArray mask,
                          InputOutputArray bgdModel, InputOutputArray fgdModel,
                          int iterCount, int mode = GC_EVAL );

CV_EXPORTS_W std::vector<std::vector<Point>> paintselection_slim( InputArray img, InputOutputArray mask,
                               InputOutputArray bgdModel, InputOutputArray fgdModel,
                               int iterCount, int mode = GC_EVAL );
```

Doing that I'm able to use the updated function in c++. Now I want to use these updated functions in both `python` and `js`, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating in the file `modules/js/src/embindgen.py` worked.